# Access CordovaWebView object

Tags: java, android, cordova, webview, cordova-plugins

How can I access CordovaWebView object in cordova android project.

I want to see the native logs in my console.

```
WebView webview = //get the main cordova web view
webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.onload = function(){alert(\"log something\");};");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work inside a plugin:

```
public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin{
    public void executeGlobalJavascript(final String jsString){
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+jsString);
            }
        });
    }

    public void someMethod(){
        executeGlobalJavascript("window.alert(\"log something\");";
    }
}
```